# Text list like numlist in siunitx

Tags: lists

I can write, using `siunitx`,

```
\numlist[parse-numbers=false]{\text{“Text 1”};\text{“Text 2”};\text{“Text 3”}}
```

to get something like

> “Text 1”, “Text 2” and “Text 3”

but how can I modify the command (or perhaps use another, better, package) so that

```
\textlist{Text 1;Text 2;Text 3}
```

gives me

> Labels “Text 1”, “Text 2” and “Text 3”

if there are more than one and

> Label “Text 1”

if only one? (“Label”/“Labels” is a ‘prefix’.)

TIA.

Comment: Would you be interested in a LuaLaTeX-based solution? Please advise.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is. I use Overleaf and PDFLaTex TeX Live 2023. Could it be solved in a "perhaps old" configuration as well?

Comment: I take this to mean "no"...